# Why my WSL ubuntu 18.04 is showing me black screen?

Tags: bash, windows-subsystem-for-linux

I was trying to use WSL, so i enabled it & virtualization's setting in control panel>windows feature on/off restarted pc, opened Ubuntu 18.04 in administrative mode. The CLI opened but did't show me anything, i waited for more than 30min 
[image]

but nothing happened,

It was showing black screen.Then this window got closed after pressingEnter

I did't understand what's the problem. and how to fix it. I searched it on youtube, but no one had encountered this problem.

Comment: Cross-posted: https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/575007/why-my-wsl-ubuntu-18-04-is-showing-me-black-screen

Answer (score 1):

Do you see the **select** on the title bar?  This means that you have clicked on the window and it has stopped, waiting for a response.  The same thing happens with the cmd prompt.  Just click in the window again and hit return.

Answer (score 0):

I fixed going to powershell as admin and running the install command again, the WSL just opened normally.

wsl --install -d ubuntu